# Unit Testing Json Result

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing

In my controller I have the following Json method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetStatuses()
{
    var allItems = rep.GetStatuses()
            .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
            .Select(i => i.Name);

    return Json(new { Items = allItems });
}
```

The method GetStatuses returns a list of statuses ( List ).

In my unit test I get the result:

```
JsonResult result = testController.GetStatuses() as JsonResult;
```

But I do not know how to deserialize the result back to List so that I can interrogate the results.

Comment: As an aside, why do you have `as JsonResult` when that's the declared return type anyway?

Comment: var result = testController.GetStatuses(); is enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just parse the JSON, e.g. using Json.NET:

```
JsonResult result = testController.GetStatuses();
string json = (string) result.Data;
List<Status> statuses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Status>>(json);
// Check statuses
```

Comment: So basically you test the round trip: serialize and deserialize in the same test. Good idea, because custom converters might have bugs in only one direction.

Comment: Consider if a different json lib should be used for the deserialization depending what you are trying to test.